# Swift - tableview bringSubviewToFront

Tags: swift

I have created a tableview but cannot get it to come to the front of my storyboard.  I have a background image view that my tableview is sitting behind and not coming to front.

```
self.view?.addSubview(self.tableviwe!)
        self.view?.bringSubviewToFront(self.tableviwe!)
```

Comment: Did you create the tableView in the Storyboard ?

Comment: no i did it programatically  @IBOutlet var tableviwe: UITableView! then in viewDidLoad self.view?.addSubview(self.tableviwe!)

Comment: if you didn't create tableview in storyboard remove IBOutlet keyword a and let var tableviwe: UITableView! only

Comment: am i to change IBOutlet to let var tableviwe:UITableView!   ?

Comment: You have to change to var tableviwe:UITableView?

Comment: this still doesn't bring it to the front

Comment: Did you set a frame on the tableView? maybe it doesn't have any size?

Comment: self.tableviwe = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(110, 40, 100, 320))  .  If i remove the image view i have for a background image i can see that this tableview is being created but it won't come in front of the image view (which i did editor -> arrange -> send to back)

Comment: You might want to send your imageView to the back by doing `sendSubviewToBack(imageView)'

Comment: please paste the code for the background if programmatically created, the object you add to the view first is considered at the back of the stack, read here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203010/how-do-i-change-the-z-index-or-stack-order-of-uiview

Answer (score 0):

Just add the tableView after the imageView.

```
view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
view.addSubview(tableView)
```