# How do I change the z index or stack order of UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview, ios8, z-index

I've stacked a UIView on top of an existing controller in an effort to create a gradient layer. However, when I load the view the new UIView (naturally) is on top of everything.

Relevant Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myGradientView: GradientView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.myGradientView.gradientWithColors(UIColor.whiteColor(), UIColor.blueColor())
    }
}
```

I've done some searching and I found [an answer in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631878/how-to-set-iphone-ui-view-z-index) that explains to use:

> [parentView bringSubviewToFront:view];

I don't know objective-c and am fairly new to Swift, if someone could shine some light on this I would appreciate it.

### My Question:

How do I change the z index or stack order of a UIView in Swift?

Comment: these are two different languages @Ben

Comment: no worries, I need to learn how to read Objective-C

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I would recommend looking in the `UIView` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html), where are several methods listed for the manipulation of the order of subviews:

> ```
> bringSubviewToFront(_:)
> sendSubviewToBack(_:)
> removeFromSuperview()
> insertSubview(_:atIndex:)
> insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)
> insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)
> exchangeSubviewAtIndex(_:withSubviewAtIndex:)
> ```

In your situation, you could try:

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(myGradientView)
// self is your view controller in this case.
```

Alternatively, because you created the `myGradientView` in IB, you could change the view hierarchy to change which views appeared on top. Here's a picture to illustrate:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: wow... that update makes me facepalm really hard. I can't believe i didn't figure that out

Comment: what if you have 5 subviews and you want to move the 2nd one to second to last?

Comment: Great! Thanks! Nice that insertSubview methods don't actually add view as another subview, just change position of already added view! Thats cool!

Answer (score 11):

the above answer of

`bringSubviewToFront(_:) sendSubviewToBack(_:)`

has changed:

**In Swift 3.0**

```
view.sendSubview(toBack:yourUIView)
view.bringSubview(toFront:yourUIView)
```

**In Swift 4.0 && Swift 5.0**

```
view.sendSubviewToBack(yourUIView)
view.bringSubviewToFront(yourUIView)
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue